# Sorry this video is not valid for streaming to this device in android

Tags: android, video, audio, recording

We are not getting any solution for the warning which is occurring when we are trying to play the recorded audio and video. The warning is

> sorry this video is not valid for streaming to this device'.

We are using the following code which was already worked well in previous device(Nexus One).

```
 recorder = new MediaRecorder();
 recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
 recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
 recorder.setVideoSize(176, 144);
 recorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
 recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
 recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
 recorder.setMaxDuration(30000);
 recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
 recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);
 recorder.prepare();
 recorder.start();
```

And our device Samsung Galaxy Pop S5570 will support only mp3 and mp4 so we tried by using the following code also. Please suggest me the below code is correct, for recording mp4 video format

```
 recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
 recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
 recorder.setVideoSize(176, 144);
 recorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
 recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H263);
 recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
 recorder.setMaxDuration(30000);
 recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
 recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);
```

Pleas provide any code available for recording the mp4 video and mp3 audio format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try to use following Settings

```
            mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
            mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(width, height);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(videoFramePerSecond);
```

where

```
private final int width = 1280;
    private final int height = 720;
    private final int videoFramePerSecond = 30;
```

This has worked for me

Comment: Hey Balban shah, I place above code in my application it is recording,I place the recorded video in list while playing this video in Samsung galxy pop s5570 which will support mp4 for playing video.Showing the warning sorry this video is not valid for streaming to this device. Please suggest me how to solve this problem.Thanks in advance

Comment: ok add following in output file
`long name = new Date().getTime();
mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/"+Long.toString(name)+".mp4");`

I hope this will work now

Comment: I place the same code in my application.while we are recording,It is recording and playing the video. But in our application when we click on save button then we send that recorded video to server.when we click on refresh button,we are showing all the recorded videos in list from server.when we click on each list item it showing warning sorry this video is not valid for streaming to this device. Please suggest me how to solve this problem.Thanks in advance

Comment: to play the Video from File this is the coding
`Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);        
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(list.get(position))), "video/*");
        startActivity(intent);`
`list.get(position)` == path of video file stored

Comment: I used the same code for playing video(in place of * I am using mp4). I am getting the same issue. I didn't understand where the issue is? Please suggest me. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: please not use mp4 in place of *. by Same code I am creating mp4 format and playing that video by above code.

Comment: I use the same code.I change to * instead of mp4.I am recording the video in mp4 getting same warning sorry this video is not valid for streaming to this device.please provide the code that support mp4 for recording video.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey Balban shah,I am using the intent to record the video,Through Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);  after recording complete.By click on save button am getting the recorded video through

Comment: protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
     switch(requestCode)
     {
      case 0: if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
      {
              recordedVideoUri = data.getData();
              System.out.print("recordedVideoUri"+recordedVideoUri);
              getMessageTitle();
          }
     }
    }

Comment: I am sending the same uri to server through multipart/form-data in bytes.As I am retrieving the same list.Playing the recorded video It showing the warning in Samsung galxy pop s5570.please suggest me how to solve this problem.Thank in advance.

Comment: I am not sure but may be things which are coming from server is not correct. please be sure over this. try to play that file in other application.